# Cant move a single app to SD card on Samsung A21s

Tags: sd-card, storage

I got an A21s yesterday and a new SD card but when I try to move apps over to it, it shows no option to change storage. This is for every single app, even ones I know should be able to move over. Had Samsung phones for years so know how to do it, it just won't let me. In which case the phone is useless if I can only use my SD card for photos.

I've formatted it, unmounted it, formatted it, turned phone off, turned phone on, looked at every single setting, even downloaded apps2sd, still impossible

[image]

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info

Comment: http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.heagoo.sdcardmovable